# Closing/clearing mock socket between tests

Tags: websocket, cypress

I'm using `mock-socket` to mock websockets calls.

I've got a test working but it only works for one test, then it says that the mock server is already listening on that url:

```js
describe('mock socket method 1', () => {
  let mockSocket;
  let mockServer;
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/', {
      onBeforeLoad(win: Window): void {
        // @ts-ignore
        cy.stub(win, 'WebSocket', url => {
          mockServer = new Server(url).on('connection', socket => {
            console.log('mock socket connected');
            mockSocket = socket;
          });
          if (!mockServer) return new WebSocket(url);
        });
      },
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockSocket.close()
  });

  it('gets a message', () => {
    const object = _createSettingsApiPutPayload(defaultSettingsState)
    mockSocket.send(JSON.stringify(object));
    cy.contains('Motion threshold')
  });
  it('gets a message', () => {
    const object = _createSettingsApiPutPayload(defaultSettingsState)
    mockSocket.send(JSON.stringify(object));
    cy.contains('Motion threshold')
  });
});
```

If I change the method to `before()` instead of `beforeEach` it works, but then I don't get a fresh environment for each test. I tried `mockSocket.close()` in `afterEach()` as you can see, but that doesn't work. I've tried `cy.reload()` but that gives a CORS error!

The error appears to be thrown at

```
> 15 | ReactDOM.render(
  16 |   <AppWrapper/>,
  17 |   document.getElementById('root'),
  18 | );
```

`AppWrapper` is a `AppContainer` wrapped in redux's `Provider`, `AppContainer` connects `App` to redux, and here's `App`:

```js
class App extends Component<AppProps> {

  settingsSubscription: W3CWebSocket;

  componentDidMount(): void {
    // subscribe to websockets
    this.settingsSubscription = this.subscribeToSettings(urls.SETTINGS_WS);

  }

  /**
   * Sets up the websockets subscription to the settings.
   * @param url the url of the websocket server
   * @return the subscription object
   */
  subscribeToSettings(url: string): W3CWebSocket {
    let settingsSubscription = new W3CWebSocket(url);
    settingsSubscription.onopen = () => console.log('WebSocket Client Connected (settings)');
    settingsSubscription.onclose = () => console.log('WebSocket Client Disconnected (settings)');
    settingsSubscription.onmessage = (message: MessageEvent) => this.handleSettingsMessage(message);
    return settingsSubscription;
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation they use `mockServer.stop()` to stop the mockServer instead of closing the mockSocket. That's what I am doing and most probably what you need as well.

Here's the snippet I am referring to:

```js
 // NOTE: this timeout is for creating another micro task that will happen after the above one
  setTimeout(() => {
    t.is(app.messages.length, 1);
    t.is(app.messages[0], 'test message from mock server', 'we have subbed our websocket backend');
    mockServer.stop(t.done);
  }, 100);
```

Here's the link to the repo:
https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket/